# Youtube player API playVideo returns api_video_info as player_204

Tags: javascript, actionscript-3, youtube, youtube-javascript-api, chromeless

Some videos fail to load in AS3 chromless player although they play
fine on the youtube site. I have checked that those videos aren't disabled
for embedded player. The same thing not only happens to my player, it
also happens to the demo player on youtube demo page.
The problem seems to be intermittent. I have played this video
successfully in as3 chromeless player before but sometimes it will
fail and there is no error event fired in youtube chromless player.
If I take a look at the protocol trace, the request after
api_video_info is player_204 (indicating streamingerror) instead of
the normal get_video request. Can you shed some light on what
happened ?

Comment: I had the same problem when I made a custom video player for youtube, but the problem only showed up when I was testing it on my local machine. Have you tried uploading it to a web server and testing it?

Comment: Yeah, same problem on the server as well.

Answer (score 0):

Some Youtube videos cannot be played inside the Chromeless player. Sometimes its because the video has been blocked on copyright reasons, sometimes its because the author has restricted this video from the chromeless player.

Have a look here for more info:

http://apiblog.youtube.com/2011/12/understanding-playback-restrictions.html